# Can Apache Tika Server be configured to use authentication of any sort?

Tags: java, solr, jar, jetty, apache-tika

I'm interested in using Apache Tika server for various processing tasks for multiple clients within my organization's ecosystem.

My organization is very large, however, and instead of letting Tika Server be open to the "world" [of my Intranet], however, I'd prefer to place some sort of authentication in front of it. HTTP Auth should be sufficient.

It looks like Tika is using Jetty. With Solr, there are configuration XML files to enable auth, but -- not being a strong Java developer -- I think that must be specific to Solr's personal integration. Is there a way to do this with Tika, as well? Or must I either proxy requests or customize Tika source and rebuild?

Comment: Your best bet would probably be to help finish the work to package the Tika Server as a War (in addition to the current runnable jar), then deploy that to something like Tomcat + enable auth in the normal way

Comment: but... but... I'm an idiot!

Comment: Ticket for it is [TIKA-894](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-894), some work has been done, probably your best bet is to join the dev list and volunteer to help finish it!

Comment: How about putting it behind a local proxy and require client certificate authentication (or any other form of authentication) via the proxy?